# plot cpt.var: Use values from dataframe for axis

Tags: r, plot, axis

When I try to plot the result from a changepoint analysis using `cpt.var` from the changepoint package, the resulting values on the x-axis are integers starting from 0 instead of the values from my dataframe (which are integers combining year and week). When I just plot my the data from my data frame the x-axis is correct, but when plotting the result of the `cpt.var` my x-values are gone

I have searched online for answers but cannot find a solution. I hope someone can help me out.

The syntax is more complex than the example below but it comes down to the same issue: plotting **the dataframe** using `plot(df, type="l")` returns correct values on the x-axis, plotting the result of the **changepoint analysis** using `plot(vvalue)` does not.

```
library(changepoint)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,text = 
                   "YEAR_WEEK N 
200801 12
200802 5
200803 0
200804 6
200805 0
200806 0
200807 4
200808 5
200809 3
200810 25
200811 36
200812 5
200813 2

         ")

vvalue <- cpt.var(df$N, method = "PELT", penalty = "BIC")
plot(vvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(vvalue, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at=1:13, labels=df[,1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works for 'fixed' ticks, but when I try a more general approach like axis(1, at=df$YEAR_WEEK, labels=df$YEAR_WEEK) it returns no values in the plot at all. Do you have a solution for this as well?

Comment: A more general solution would be this: `plot(vvalue, xaxt = "n");
axis(1, at=seq(1:length(df$YEAR_WEEK)), labels=df$YEAR_WEEK)`

Comment: One final question: If I adjust the number of ticks on the x axis using at=seq(1,length(df$YEAR_WEEK), by=25) I get the (obvious) error : 'at' and 'labels' lengths differ. How to solve this?